# Is there any performance difference between Hibernate Interceptors and Events?

Tags: java, hibernate, listener, interceptor

I would like to ask if there is a difference between Hibernate Interceptors and Events in terms of performance ?

Let's take these two into consideration :

**INTERCEPTOR**

```
public class MyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        //something done here
    }
}
```

**LISTENER**

```
public class MyEventListener implements PreInsertEventListener {  
    @Override
    public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent preInsertEvent) {
       //same thing here
    }
}
```

Assume that I can do the same thing with both. Which one I should prefer in terms of performance ?

Thanks in advance.